# What is the best way to check if a string from a text file equals what's in JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, io, awt

I have to write a program that has a log-in window.
I need to check if the username and the password all satisfy what is written in a text file.

the text file which has named as: "pass" contains the following :
*Admin:icsPro8%*

In my validUserName method, I wrote these two lines under the try block to extract what is in the text file "pass" :

```
try{
   InputFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("pass.txt"));
   String name = InputFile.nextLine();
}
```

But unfortunately, I got this error: "name has private access in java.awt.Component"
why this happened ? and how to fix it ?

Comment: I don't see any code where you're comparing any Strings. Also, is the error occurring in the code your showing? It sure doesn't look that way to me. Please show the full error message, and please show the offending line of code.

Comment: And storing your password in a plain text file ... not what I would call secure. Also, there is `JPasswordField` iso `JTextField` if you want the user to input a password

Comment: Passwords file is in plain text file on the computer they have access to? It would be better to have passwords hashed.

Answer (score 1):

You have initialized the variable name inside try block, so you cannot access it outside the try block.
If you want to access it globally try to declare it outside the try block.